# Пример при выводе: 8 = 5 + 3, 8 = 3 + 5. Как после первого найденного числа вернуться в цикл

Tags: python

```
for t in range(4, 10000):
    if t%2 == 0:
        for i in range(len(m)):
            for j in range(len(m)):
                if t == m[i] + m[j]:
                    print(t,"=", m[j],"+", m[i])
```

Comment: я ничего не понял. что такое m, например? что вы хотите получить?

Comment: Пожалуйста, сначала заявите, чего вы хотите добиться своим кодом, чтобы мы могли его обсудить - см. [Что такое «Ошибка молотка» или «Ошибка XY»?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/710/233990)

Comment: Выкинуть третий цикл и подумать.

Answer (score 2):

У range() может быть не только верхняя граница, но и нижняя. Просто сделай

```
for j in range(i+1, len(m))
```

Тогда повторов не будет.

Ещё у range() может быть шаг. Сделай

```
for t in range(4, 10000, 2)
```

и тогда станет не нужна проверка на чётность.

Но на самом деле тут никакой перебор с кучей циклов не нужен. Задача решается простым вычитанием.

Comment: Думаю, он хотел остановиться на первом результате, а не просто не выводить коммутативные.

Answer (score 1):

```
for t in range(4, 10000, 2):
  for x in m:
    if t-x in m:
      print(t, "=", x,"+", t-x)
      break
```

PS: Можно сделать эффективнее, но вроде никто не просил.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, то так например:

```
for t in range(4, 10000):
    def search(t):
      if t%2 == 0:
        for i in range(len(m)):
            for j in range(len(m)):
                if t == m[i] + m[j]:
                    print(t,"=", m[j],"+", m[i])
                    return
    search(t)
```

Comment: `def` внутри цикла - это ужасно, не делайте так ))  Ну, если у вас нет цели специально дополнительно замедлить код.